# Manually delete object tree in entity-Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4

If I want to delete manually an object and all it's children, 
How can I do it **(I don't want to use cascade-delete)**

When I'm trying to iterate over the children list - I get an exception because I'm changing the collection inside foreach - and that's a problem... any other way to do it ?
(I'm setting each time state to deleted).

```
var myAssignemnt = (from s in context.Assignments.Include("ActivityInAssignments").Where(s => s.AssignmentID == AssignmentID) select s).FirstOrDefault();

foreach (ActivityInAssignment acc in myAssignemnt.ActivityInAssignments)
{
  context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(acc, System.Data.EntityState.Deleted);
}
context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myAssignemnt, System.Data.EntityState.Deleted);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try `... in myAssignemnt.ActivityInAssignments.ToList()`

Comment: can you explain why it works with ToList() and not original collection ? (I though the problem is in the foreach function and not inside the ActivityInAssignment collection.

Comment: The problem is in the collection, It reacts to items being 'removed' and that invalidates the foreach. ToList makes a copy of the references and that copy is immune to the changes.